# AS400 - Parse JSON and store the fields into DB2 table

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have got requirement to parse a JSON document that will be passed to a stored procedure inside a CLOB, and store its details into a DB2 table.

I cannot make use of JSON_TABLE function as I am still using IBM i V7R1.

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Pre native built in support for JSON in 7.2 I used this third party tool ported to the iSeries and maintained by Scott Klement [YAJL (Yet Another JSON Library)](https://www.scottklement.com/yajl/)

Comment: YAJL works great for projects like this.  I think it should be mentioned that Scott Klement didn't write this API.  He ported it over to the IBM i and maintains that port though.

Comment: My mistake on the built by Scott Klement part, Thank you for the correction. I just like to give credit were it is due, looks like that backfired this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've used this apis on production. Excellent work.

[Mihael Schmidt's Json Parser](https://rpgnextgen.com/index.php?content=examples)